# Crear sesiones seguras con PHP

Tags: php, session, seguridad

He estado leyendo este [artículo de OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) (muy completo) donde tratan más de 100 **puntos ha tener en cuenta para que las sesiones sean seguras** (Tanto de **PHP** como con otros lenguajes o sistemas).

Lo que ocurre es que hablan casi todo el rato sobre las cookies y las formas que tienen los hackers de obtener el **ID de sesión** desde ellas.

Mi pregunta es: En el caso de usar las **sesiones PHP**, ¿Es tan grave que se conozca el ID de sesión de la cookie que genera PHP con el nombre de PHPSESSID? (En el caso de que sean reveladas por algún fallo en la seguridad)

Teniendo en cuenta, que al iniciar la sesión, se almacena en la variable `$_SESSION` el email del usuario y un código único y permanente de ese usuario que nunca es revelado, y tan solo se manipula por el lado del servidor.

También quiero aclarar, que cada vez que el usuario va a hacer una acción "importante" como acceder a los datos personales, eliminar algo, etc, estos dos datos son verificados desde la base de datos.

Además, en todas y cada una de las solicitudes se verifica que existan datos en la variable $_SESSION (con el formato y longitud adecuados, cosa que nadie conoce), y que yo sepa, el hecho de conocer la ID de sesión de los cookies no puede hacer que se añada contenido "válido" a esa variable, y por lo tanto la sesión no sería aceptada.

Todas estas dudas me vienen porque he visto que [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet)  está tratando la seguridad de las sesiones como si el único identificador de las mismas fueran las cookies, y es posible que usando otros métodos fuera así, pero **quiero saber si en mi caso es necesario hacer TODO lo que mencionan**.

Espero que se me haya entendido. Saludos.

Comment: Si interceptan el contenido de la cookie `PHPSESSID` pueden suplantar tu identidad y aunque no puedan averiguar tu usuario y contraseña, pueden actuar dentro de la aplicación como si fueras tú. Si la aplicación no solicita las credenciales antiguas al hacer un cambio de contraseña se podría realizar un robo de credenciales, si no se solicita autorización al hacer un cambio de dirección de email podrían solicitar nueva contraseña a una dirección que no gestionas, etc. Enumera **"quiero saber si en mi caso es necesario hacer TODO lo que mencionan"** y te respondemos a cada cuestión.

Comment: @OscarGarcia De acuerdo, entonces es que los datos de la variable $_SESSION están en la Cookie? Porque sino, no entiendo de qué forma podrá pasar el filtro de "Tener datos en esa variable y que sean correctos". Como ya he dicho, cuando se va a hacer algo importante, mas que verificar si hay datos, se comparan esos datos (Email y SSID) con la BD. Gracias y saludos

Comment: Si robas la cookie de sesión de un navegador y la usas en otro navegador diferente, desde el punto de vista del servidor sois la misma persona ya que el contenido de esa cookie es la que se usa para acceder al contenido de las variables `$_SESSION` almacenadas en el lado del servidor.

Comment: Ahh... vale, eso no lo sabía, entonces ya me has resuelto la duda. Muchas gracias.